# Why is the value of variable changing without changing it in the program?

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

The value of variable is changing automatically after the input "abcdefghijklmnop", which is 16 characters as required. I cant understand why is it changing automatically. I would appreciate any help I can get for this.

Here is the code:

```
void test(void){
    char    arr[16];
    int     magic = 42;

    printf("magic = %d\n", magic);
    
    printf("Enter a character string: ");
    
    getString(arr, 16 + 1);
    printf("The length of string [%s] is %d\n", arr, stringLength(arr));
    
    printf("magic = %d\n", magic);

}
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    test();
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You told the function there is `16+1` elements, but there are only `16`. Dont forget the string terminator. The array `char arr[16]` can only store a string of length `15`.

Comment: What variable changes? What is `getString()`?

Comment: You need to change the size of your array, dont forget the `\0`

Comment: You observe Undefined Behavior by accessing your array `arr` out of bounds. To store 16 character C string you need at least array size 17

Comment: When you write outside the bounds of an array, one of the many bad things that can happen is that you overwrite some other variable that happens to be located at that address in memory.  Focus on how to make your code not do that in the first place.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Is `getString()` from the CS50 library?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the explanation, it makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You told `getString` to read more characters than `arr` can hold and those extra characters were stored to memory outside of `arr`, thus overwriting `magic`.

To store a string that's N characters long you need an array that's *at least* N+1 elements wide.  A 16 element `char` array can store a string *up to* 15 characters long, plus the string terminator.  Instead of telling `getString` to read 16+1 characters, you should have told it to read 16-1.

Actually, you should have told it

```
getString(arr, sizeof arr - 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can solve your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 20

void test(void){
    char    arr[MAX];
    int     magic = 42, stringLen = 0;

    printf("magic = %d\n", magic);
    
    printf("Enter a character string: ");
    
    fgets(arr, MAX, stdin);
    stringLen = strlen(arr);

    if(arr[stringLen -1] == '\n'){
        arr[stringLen -1] = '\0';
        stringLen = strlen(arr);

    }
    printf("The length of string [%s] is %d ", arr, stringLen);
    
    printf("magic = %d\n", magic);

}
int main()
{
    test();
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```